If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c$, where $c$ is a real number, prove the following
If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c$, where $c$ is a real number, prove the following:

$\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]=\infty$
$\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]=\infty $ if $c>0$
$\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]=-\infty$ if $c<0$

I have at least attempted these problems, however I want some verification that these are correct solutions.

For $M>0$, we must find a $\delta>0$ such that:

$f(x) + g(x)>M\;$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$.
Since $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty\;$ we know that for any $M_1 >0$, there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that:
$f(x)>M_1$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_1\;\;(1)$
Since $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c$, we know that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that:
$\vert g(x)-c\vert<\varepsilon$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_2 \;\;(2)$
The following is some preliminary work:
We know from $(1)$ that $f(x) + g(x) > M_1 + g(x)$
We also know from $(2)$ that $g(x)>c-\varepsilon$
We can then use this to get $f(x)+g(x)>M_1+g(x)>M_1+c-\varepsilon$
If we let $M_1=M+\varepsilon-c\;$ for $M>0$, we would get $f(x)+g(x)>M$. (One question on this part is is it ok to say we assume we choose $\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon>c$, therefore holding $M_1>0$? Is this even necessary?)
From this, we can construct a solution.
Given $M>0$, choose $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. If $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$, then $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_1$ and $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_2$.
$f(x)+g(x)>M_1+g(x)>M+\varepsilon-c+c-\varepsilon=M$
In summary, $f(x)+g(x)>M\;$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$.
This in limit form is $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]=\infty$

For $M>0$, we must find a $\delta>0$ such that:

$f(x)g(x)>M\;$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$.
The following is some preliminary work:
We know from $(2)$ that $g(x) >c-\varepsilon$. We can choose $\varepsilon$ such that $c>\varepsilon\;$ (A similar question is posed: Can we choose $\varepsilon$ such that $c>\varepsilon$)$?$
Since $g(x)>0$, we notice the following from (1)
$f(x)>M_1\rightarrow f(x)g(x)>M_1g(x)>M_1(c-\varepsilon)$
We can let $M_1=M/(c-\varepsilon)$, then $f(x)g(x)>(M/(c-\varepsilon))(c-\varepsilon)=M$
With this work, we can construct a solution.
Given $M>0$, choose $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. If $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$, then $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_1$ and $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_2$.
$f(x)g(x)>M_1g(x)>(M/(c-\varepsilon))(c-\varepsilon)=M$
In summary, $f(x)g(x)>M$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$. This in limit form is $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]=\infty \; c>0$.

For $N<0$, we must find a $\delta>0$ such that:

$f(x)g(x)<N\;$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$.
The following is some preliminary work:
We know from $(2)$ that $g(x)<\varepsilon+c$. If we choose $\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon<-c$, $g(x)$ must be negative for $\delta_2$ (Same question posed previously).
Combining this with $(1)$, we see that $f(x)g(x)<M_1g(x)<M_1(\varepsilon+c)$
Since by the condition of $\varepsilon+c<0$ and $M_1>0$, the right side is negative, so we are on the right track. If $M_1=N/(\varepsilon+c)$ where $N<0$, this satisfies $M_1>0$ and we get the following.
$f(x)g(x)<(N/(\varepsilon+c))(\varepsilon+c)=N$
With this, we construct the following solution.
Given $N<0$, choose $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. If $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$, then $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_1$ and $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta_2$.
$f(x)g(x)<M_1g(x)<M_1(\varepsilon+c)<(N/(\varepsilon+c))(\varepsilon+c)=N$
In summary, $f(x)g(x)<N$ whenever $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$
As you can see, I asked some questions throughout the post so I am wondering if my line of reasoning is correct. Thank you in advance.

By replacing $g(x)$ with $-g(x)$, problem $3$ could easily be proven from problem $2$. So, only problems $1$ and $2$ need to be proven.

@GeoffreyTrang Since I am following "Calculus, 5th Edition: Stewart, James", he proved $\lim_{x\to a}cf(x)=c\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ for the case that both limits of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist. He also made clear that if the limit is infinity, that the limit does not exist but is denoted by the infinity sign as the reason why it does not exist. Replacing $g(x)$ with $-g(x)$ as a way of proving that the limit tends to negative infinity would imply using the previous theorem, right? I understand if I am saying incorrect stuff, I just want to express my doubt and I would love to hear why I'm wrong.

If $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c$, then of course, $\lim_{x\to a} -g(x)=-c$. This is a special case of Stewart's result where the constant multiplier is $-1$. So, problem $3$ follows immediately from problem $2$.
